# Sticky Menu on the side of a div that slides

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a sticky menu at the left side of a div which links to the anchor tags of the content and slide to the top of the content. However I want this sticky menu to stay attached to the div. I tried to set its position to absolute but then when I expand the window its position changes horizontally. Below is the jquery function I use for the slide animation.

```
$(function() {
 $('.slider a').bind('click', function(event) {
 var $anchor = $(this);

 $('html, body').stop().animate({
   scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
 }, 1000);

event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mosmic/319d4bcL/1/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/319d4bcL/4/

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes? It's a pretty clear question.

Comment: @cameronjonesweb not exactly. The sticky menu still stays at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated JSFiddle with a fix to your problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/319d4bcL/2/

I added the following CSS to your menu:

```
#sticky-menu {
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left:-30px;
}
```

The problem with `position-fixed` and `left` or `right` absolute values is that the div stops being related to the parent and takes values from the viewport. This is solved by using margins instead. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean `position: fixed`?

https://jsfiddle.net/g3x70z7w/

All I did was change:

```
#sticky-menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

To...

```
#sticky-menu {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I had this previously. When I stretch the window the sticky menu seems to detach from the div it's next to.